# We have a cross-network spammer…now what?

Tags: support, spam, stack-exchange

[A recent question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2458/looking-for-thoughts-and-resources-for-making-short-film) posted to the Philosophy site got flagged as spam. I wasn't immediately convinced that the user was a spammer, as they *might* have thought their question was tangentially related to philosophy and just not read the FAQ carefully enough.

But a quick glance at their [network user profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1154734/chandni-batra?tab=accounts) provided I was wrong to have given them the initial benefit of the doubt. It turns out that they've posted the identical question to *several* of the SE 2.0 sites:

- [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/looking-for-thoughts-and-resources-for-making-short-film)
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/looking-for-thoughts-and-resources-for-making-short-film)
- [Musical Practice & Performance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5810/looking-for-thoughts-and-resources-for-making-short-film)
- [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/looking-for-thoughts-and-resources-for-making-short-film)

...and on the last two, it's *even more clearly off topic* than it is on Philosophy.

Is this our first cross-network spammer? I find that hard to believe, but I can't find any trails indicating how this might have been previously handled.

I'm not sure what the proper course of action is here. Should it be handled separately on each site? Should one of the moderators send them a private message and optimistically attempt to educate them on what they've done wrong? Do we just need to drop the network-wide ban hammer?

Comment: Not the first. [This user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1277257/user1277257?tab=accounts) spammed [this (10k only)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760898/codesoncloud-safe-your-code-on-cloud) across a dozen or more sites just last week. Everything was cleaned up in time, but not all accounts were destroyed.

Comment: In the past I've flagged on the "worst" site initially and then provided one flag per site where they'd also been posting, referring to the fact that this was also seen on another site. I'm guessing the mods discussed it in TL, but it seemed to get handled as I'd have expected.

Comment: It might be worth raising it in "the assembly" although I'm not 100% sure talking about handling spam in a public room is wise. (If spammers latched on to how they get caught there might be a hideous arms race)

Comment: I believe in network so big, the devs have red big "Nuke" button that eliminates the accounts of specific user in all sites across the network - so in such case fastest way to handle such thing is to ping a dev by whatever private communication channels you have as moderator. I know such button exist in other places with much less traffic..

Comment: Blah blah, yeah it all probably exists in a chat room. But we have this *great site here for general network-wide issues and discussions*. Why should I have to use a chat room? The devs check this site, too, and if others have suggestions (whether they're a developer, moderator, or [peon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peon)), they should be able to contribute them—at least once per issue. I didn't see that this one had been raised anywhere already.

Comment: We've had cross-network trolls, in fact we've even had [cross-internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=vgv8) trolls!

Comment: Already dealt with in Movies and I actually alerted people in TL, I guess just got pushed out :p

Answer (score 5):

Cross-network spammers can be issued a network-wide ban by the staff (and such a ban has happened before). The most efficient and effective way to get this done is to contact team@stackexchange.com, informing them about the user's activity, with links to their network profiles and any relevant details.

Here's [a list of all their network profiles](https://stackexchange.com/users/1154734/chandni-batra?tab=accounts) to get you started. I should also note that this person's name and gravatar seem very familiar...

Comment: Don't look now, but I linked to that network profile in my question. Looks like I'm already started. :-)

Comment: @The Establishment: Oh whoops, I missed that while focusing on the list.